# How to create a round Button with a corner overlay

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I would like to create a `Button` which looks like this:

[image: Button image]

This is what I tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#00000000">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPinterest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/pinterest"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btnPinterest"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I am not satisfied, it doesn't look like the `Button` I showed above. For example the text a text is too close. Can anyone help me replicate this `Button` more accurately?

If anyone needs it, this is the overlayed image:

[image: Notification Icon]

Comment: Can you edit an image of what you currently have into your question? That would make it a lot easier to understand the problem.

Comment: You could use just a  single ImageButton and override it's onDraw callback to draw the corner element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gimp to produce four images and save them in drawable. your images must have that blue triangle on the top left and you must type the text "Pinterest" and other design into the image.

Then create a new XML file and put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_enabled"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_focused"
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_default"/>
</selector>
```

That will give you a custom button for 4 states : 1) Disabled 2) Pressed 3) Focused 4) Enabled(default)

Comment: thank much, i think i should use custom view because i have a lot of button like this